# Compound Interest Question. Any Help

Tags: calculus, economics

> The 50 000 USD you have saved up by just paying 1000 USD into your account
>   every 1-st of the month for a number of months. The account pays you
>   interests at the rate of 3 % p.a compounded monthly.
>
> Calculate now how many months are required to save up the 50 000 USD.

My solution:

Let us guess 49 months and we get:

1000*(1.03)*49 = 50 470

So after 49 months, I save up 50 470 USD

Anything wrong? Thanks

Comment: In your solution you made just one payment, but the problem asks for a payment *every* first of the month.  Further, the 3% interest is per annum, but you are taking 3% per month.  You should only be earning 0.25% per month.

Comment: Just one payment? But I multiplied it by 49, so I got the 50 000. So we conclude that it requires 49 months. No?

Comment: you are right. I did a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Each month your earn interest on the previous months balance.

Or you have one payment that receives interest every month.  One payment that receives interest every month but the first.  One payment that receives interest every month but the first two. etc.

$B = P\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n} (1+y)^n\\
50,000 = 1000\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n} (1.0025)^n$

Now you need to sum a finite geometric series to find $n.$

Comment: Cant I just try some random n to get the solution? I'm not enough good at finite geometric series

Comment: You can set up a spreadsheet, and keep track of the partial sums as $n$ grows, eventually your sum will cross the required threshold..

Comment: Hello Doug M. Can it be the solution? 1000*(1.0025)*50(months) = 50 125. Thanks

Comment: No, that doesn't look like the sum of a series to me...  47 months. $50,000 = 1,000 \frac {1.0025^n - 1}{1.0025 - 1} \implies 1.0025^n = 50(0.0025)+1\implies n = \frac {\log 1.125}{\log 1.0025}$

Comment: Thank you very much Doug M

Answer (score 0):

$S=\$\,50,000$, $P=\$\, 1,000$ and $i=\frac{i^{(12)}}{12}=\frac{3\%}{12}=0.25\%$.

Using the future value of an [annuity due](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annuity#Annuity-due) (payment at the beginning)
$$
S=P\,\ddot s_{\overline{n}|i}=P\cdot(1+i)\cdot\frac{(1+i)^n-1}{i}
$$
we have 
$$
n=\frac{\log\left(\frac{S}{P}\frac{i}{1+i}+1\right)}{\log(1+i)}\approx 47
$$